# How to find unknown (pseudo-random) number in crypto algorithm equation, similar to RSA

Tags: cryptography

I am trying to solve a past CTF (Capture the Flag) event crypto question. The algorithm is similar to RSA: it generates a public and private key, then encrypts the flag with the public key. It looks similar to RSA, except the encryption is done with a pseudo-random, huge `e`, the public key has 3 values, and the private key one value. Unfortunately the exercise doesn't have a writeup, so I can't see how others solved it.

The key generation is done with a prime number, up to $2^{1024}$, called $p$. 2 pseudo-random numbers are picked, $g$ and $x$, used to generate $h =  g^x \bmod p$. $(p, g, h)$ are the public key, and $x$ is the private key.

To encrypt a message $m$, another pseudo-random number $y$ is picked, used to calculate $s = h ^ y \bmod p$. The result of the encryption are 2 numbers, $c1$ and $c2$: $c1 = g \times y \bmod p$ and $c2 = m \times s \bmod p$.

All the pseudo-random numbers values are between $2$ and $2^{1024} - 2$.

For the exercise, the values of $(p, g, h)$ (the public key) are given, along with the values of $c1$ and $c2$.

To solve it, I figure the value of $y$ has to be found. If it was such that $g \times y \bmod p = 1$, it would be easy to find, but it's not. I have tested a brute forcing algorithm and it works fine with values up to $2^{10}$, as I am able to find the flag. With the real values brute forcing $y$ would take forever, as it can go up to $2^{1024} - 2$, so I assume there must be a mathematical relation between them that makes the algorithm weak, but I can't seem to find it.

Edit: in case it might make the question clearer, here are some test values, for a flag of `FLAG{PLACEHOLDER_VALUE}`

$p = 757$

$g = 623$

$h = 414$

$(c1, c2) = (306, 85)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing hinges on being able to efficiently calculate multiplicative inverses modulo $p$, which we can do via the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

We first find $g^{-1}$, which gives us $c_1 \times g^{-1} = y$. From that we can calculate $s = h^y$, and then by finding $s^{-1}$ we take $c_2 \times s^{-1} = m$ to retrieve the message, all without ever knowing what $x$ was.

Using the example values, it looks something like this (following the notation from the Wikipedia article):

| index $i$ | quotient $q_{i-1}$ | remainder $r_i$ | $s_i$ | $t_i$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 757 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 |  | 623 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 134 | 1 | -1 |
| 3 | 4 | 87 | -4 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 47 | 5 | -6 |
| 5 | 1 | 40 | -9 | 11 |
| 6 | 1 | 7 | 14 | -17 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | -79 | 96 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 93 | -113 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | -265 | 322 |
| 10 | 2 | 0 | 623 | -757 |

So $322 \times 623 - 265 \times 757 = 1$, and hence $623^{-1} \equiv 322 \mod 757$. Then $y \equiv g^{-1} c_1 = 322 \times 306 \equiv 122 \mod 757$, and with a bit of careful manipulation I *think* we get $s \equiv 414^{122} \equiv 582 \mod 757$, then repeating the EEA gives $s^{-1} = 186$, finally leading to $m \equiv 186 \times 85 \equiv 670 \mod 757$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Finding $y$ is clear to me now. 
I have a few questions though. When finding $s^{-1}$, which values are plugged into the EEA as $r_0$ and $r_1$? $757$ and $582$ ($p$ and $s$)? 
And how do we get the final message from $m = 670 \bmod 757$? Is it $186 \times 85$, and then converting that number to bytes?

Comment: If you're trying to find the inverse of $x$ mod $m$, then you're trying to solve $ax + bm = 1$ so you set $r_0 = m$ and $r_1 = x$ - so in both cases we put $r_0 = p$, and then we put $g$ in the first time and $s$ the second. Technically in this framework $m = 670$ is the message, but in computer terms you'd then read that as binary.

Comment: I see, but $m = 670$ isn't the entire message. The given flag `FLAG{PLACEHOLDER_VALUE}` converted to long int has a value of $6733198372838931630179430884192353758790689152518407549$, converted with Python's `Crypto.Util.number.bytes_to_long()` function. I now understand how to find all the variables (thanks!), but not how to get the multiplier for $m$.
Indeed, $6733...\equiv 670 \pmod {757}$. My question now is, is there a quick way to get the multiplier to go from $670$ to $6733...$, considering the long number is unknown?

Comment: With the information you've provided, you can only reconstruct $m \mod p$. Typically you would break $m$ up into shorter pieces and encrypt each of them individually.